# inject @Stateless EJB from other .ear

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss

I have a multi-ear project. Some EJB's reside in project1.ear, and I need to use it in project2.ear.

I'm trying the following:

```
@Remote
public interface MyService {

    public static final String JNDI_NAME = "service/MyService"; 

    // methods

}


@Stateless(name = MyService.JNDI_NAME, mappedName = MyService.JNDI_NAME)
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
   // implementations...
}
```

Then, in some project2.ear class, I inject the EJB like this:

```
@Stateless(name = "other/Service")
public class OtherServiceImpl implements OtherService{

    @EJB(mappedName = MyService.JNDI_NAME)
    private MyService service;
}
```

But I got a lot of "FailedToConstructException" and EJB related exception, with the following cause:

```
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: service/MyService -- service jboss.naming.context.java.service.MyService
    at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:97)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:178)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:113)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:214)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbLookupInjectionSource$1.getReference(EjbLookupInjectionSource.java:82) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 104 more
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to browse JNDI tree to see whether your `service/MyService` exists. If you're using JBoss 6, you can find instructions [here](http://geekzguru.wordpress.com/2008/01/22/howto-view-the-jndi-tree-in-jboss/). Not sure if they added it into higher versions.

Next, check packages - interface `MyService` needs to be in the same package in both ears, otherwise lookup will fail.

Finally, there's no need to have both `name` and `mappedName` attributes in `@Stateless` annotation, `mappedName` is enough. You can also try to inject `MyService` with `@EJB` annotation without any attribute, if project1.ear is only one that implements that interface, application server will inject it:

```
@EJB
private MyService service;
```

Comment: thanks, I leave it only with mappedName and it worked like a boss.